# Facebook hours graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having some troubles with `facebook graph api`. We are using graph api to update pages on facebook. The problem is that for some pages hours are not updated (only hours). `Facebook` does not throw any error, just values do not change. I have tried `koala` and `fbgraph` for `nodejs` libraries.

Here is an [example of page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Test2/1449532041979638?ref=hl&sk=info) where open hours gets updated.
And this [one](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Test/419995728143455?sk=info) does not work.
This is request body:

```
{
    "description"=>"This is a test description for NetworkProfile UK! Keep all of your listings up to date", 
    "general_info"=>"NetworkProfile UK London, InSights, NetworkProfile", 
    "phone"=>"02089610538", 
    "website"=>"www.innerballoons.com",
    "keywords"=>"NetworkProfile UK London,InSights,NetworkProfile", 
    "location"=>{
        "city"=>"London",
        "street"=>"22 Highbury Grove", 
        "zip"=>"N5 2EF"
        }, 
    "country"=>"Netherlands", 
    "latitude"=>51.5504,
    "longitude"=>-0.0970388, 
    "hours"=>{
        "mon_1_open"=>"09:00", 
        "mon_1_close"=>"15:00",
        "tue_1_open"=>"09:00", 
        "tue_1_close"=>"17:45", 
        "wed_1_open"=>"09:00", 
        "wed_1_close"=>"17:00", 
        "thu_1_open"=>"08:15", 
        "thu_1_close"=>"18:30", 
        "fri_1_open"=>"none", 
        "fri_1_close"=>"none", 
        "sat_1_open"=>"none", 
        "sat_1_close"=>"none", 
        "sun_1_open"=>"none", 
        "sun_1_close"=>"none"
        }
}
```

And response from `facebook`:

```
{"data"=>"true"}
```

Does anyone have any clue what could be the cause of this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: This may be a bug. In case you can't find a solution for an other implementation, you can file bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thanks! we have found case similar to ours https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1515351362009566/